# Weird artefacts when moving text

Tags: javascript, html, css

**HTML**

I need help, so I have this button (has no text yet) and when its hovered, a css zoom happens with transitions, however the text below it has to move. When this happens it leaves behind this weird trail. Surprisingly it does not show in the code snippet insert tool.

Video:
https://youtu.be/-gh7mJxFz8o

```js
//Game List
console.log(document.getElementById('close3').style.display);
function showGameList(){
 document.getElementById("gameList").style.display= "block";
 document.getElementById("close1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("close2").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("close3").style.display = "none";
}
function closeGameList(){
  document.getElementById("gameList").style.display= "none";
  document.getElementById("close1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("close2").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("close3").style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
/*fonts*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap');
/*general*/
html{
 max-width: 100vw;
 min-width: 100vw;
 width: 100vw;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 height: auto;
}
body{
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 height: auto;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
}
/*Navbar*/
#nav{
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
border-bottom: 5px solid gold;
top: 0%;
padding: none;
}
#navLink{
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 22%;
padding: 1%;
transition: 0.5s;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
#navLink:hover{
 background-color: gold;
 color: black;
}
#navLinkActive{
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 22.5%;
padding: 1%;
transition: 0.5s;
text-align: center;
color: black;
background-color: gold;
}
/*Home page*/
#page{
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.joinButton{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border: 5px solid gold;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}
.joinButton:hover{
 background-color: rgba(255,215,0,0.5);
 zoom: 1.25;
}
#homePageBody{
 height: 40vh;
 padding-top: 15vh;
 padding-bottom: 15vh;
}
#homePageBodySpecial{
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 15vh;
 padding-bottom: 15vh;
}
#homePageBody p{
font-size: 20px;
}
.homePageBody1{
padding-top: 15vh;
margin-top: 5vh;
 background-repeat: none;
  background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) ),    url('assets/images/backgrounds/background1.png');
}
.homePageBody2{
margin-top: 1vh;
height: auto;
min-height: 40vh;
 background-repeat: none;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) ),    url('assets/images/backgrounds/background2.png');
}
/* Game List */
#gameList{
 display: none;
 border: 5px solid gold;
 border-radius: 5%;
 width: 40vw;
 padding:2.5vw;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 transition: 1s;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#gameListItem{
 width: 30%;
 display: inline-block;
 height: auto;
}
#gameListItemImg{
 width: 30%;
}
#closeButtonSmall{
 width: 30px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border:none;
 text-align: center;
 top: 2.5%;
 right: 2.5%;
 position: relative;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: white;
}
#gameListItemFullWidth{
 width: 100%;
}
#counter1{
}
/*Animations*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>AUG</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Navbar -->
 <div id="nav">
  <a href="" id="navLinkActive"><div id="navItemActive">Home</div></a>
  <a href="" id="navLink"><div id="navItem">About</div></a>
  <a href="" id="navLink"><div id="navItem">Join</div></a>
  <a href="" id="navLink"><div id="navItem">User Center</div></a>
 </div>
 <!-- Main Body -->
 <div id="page">
 <div id="homePageBody" class="homePageBody1">
  <h1>Aussie Games</h1><br>
  <p>Description</p>
  <button class="joinButton"></button><br>
  <h2>Current Member Count</h2>
  <h3>28</h3>
 </div>
 <div id="homePageBodySpecial" class="homePageBody2">
  <h2 id="close1">What we offer</h2><br>
  <p id="close2">We offer great, inclusive communities, and competent staff for many of the games you know.</p>
  <button id="close3" class="joinButton" onclick="showGameList()">What do we offer</button>
  <div id="gameList" onclick="closeGameList()">
   <div id="gameListItemFullWidth"><p>Click window to close</p></div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/FL.png">
   <p>Flashing Lights</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/GM.png">
   <p>Garry's Mod</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/IF.png">
   <p>Infinite Flight</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/KSP.png">
   <p>Kerbal Space Program</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/MC.png">
   <p>Minecraft</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/P2.png">
   <p>Payday 2</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/RB.png">
   <p>Roblox</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/SM.png">
   <p>Surving Mars</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/TF.png">
   <p>Team Fortress</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue - I'm betting it's a bug in your browser and/or you need to update your graphics drivers.

Comment: It appears to be a browser issue as once tried in google chrome it does not happen